# RavenDB (RavenHQ) and Twilio.MVC and Newtonsoft.Json dependency

Tags: json, ravendb, nuget, twilio, json.net

I have been trying to get my app to talk to RavenHQ and have Twilio helper package installed as well.  I've tried installing the latest Raven client stable build, requiring Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8 and also the .972 client of RavenDB which requires  Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.7.  Twilio wants to update the Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.7 version to 4.5.10.  I get the "Unable to find a version of 'RavenDB.Client' that is compatible with 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.10"  Any thoughts about how to proceed or any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Force
Install-Package RavenDB.Client -version 1.0.972
```

Or if you are starting from scratch:

```
Install-Package RavenDB.Client -version 1.0.972
Install-Package RestSharp
Install-Package Twilio -IgnoreDependencies
```

Comment: Thanks, I had success with the IgnoreDependencies flag but I needed to use that  option on multiple Nuget packeges, but it finally worked.  In addition, I needed to modify my Web.config file as well, the bindingRedirect for System.Net.Http.Formatting needed to point to "4.0.0.0" instead of "4.1.0.0"

Comment: NuGet should have added the binding redirect for you.  If not, try the Add-BindingRedirect command.  See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference